# Validate US vehicle license plate numbers in a form field

Tags: forms, validation

I am proposing a form field for a mobile experience in which people can input their number plate number. It has multiple states. I am inclined towards the inline validation method (highlighted in the pink box). After hitting 'Link' or 'Connect' in the mobile keypad, there will be a check performed to see if the number plate exists in the dB or not.

I have seen that USA has multiple formats and the characters can range between 5-7: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_license_plate_designs_and_serial_formats.

Keen to get feedback on whether inline validation is feasible here and if the entire state transitions make sense?

[image]

Comment: You can create an API which takes the license plate serial as input and returns if the serial is valid or not.
You can add an onChangedListener on the text input box. To simplify, you can also add the 'valid' green checkmark below the input box. Many apps does something similar to that.